# output apache pig data to file in custom format

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I've a tab delimited data input which needs to be processed using Apache Pig due to data size.
I've successfully loaded the data and even analyzed it but I'd like to store output to a file in the original format instead of storing the tuples.

```
Sample Input
A \t B
A \t B

Sample Output
A \t B
A \t B
```

instead of (A,B),(A,B)

```
 Store D into 'output' using PigStorage('\n')
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: What does your current output actually look like? SHould that be a tab character in the PigStorage line too?

Comment: something like that:                                                        1,{(A,1),(D,1)} \n
2,{(B,2),(C,2)} I'd like to get same format as the input.

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded the input that is tab separated but you are writing it back **new line (\n)** separated.

Try:

```
Store D into 'output' using PigStorage('\t');
```

or

```
Store D into 'output' using PigStorage(); -- tab is the default delimiter
```

As for the specific format of the output, I'd suggest you look into the flatten [1] operator.

[1] http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Flatten+Operator